# Outlook preselect sender

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

We use Office365 and Exchange Online (as part of out Office365 plan). We have two users and a shared mailbox. Both users have full access to the shared mailbox and added it to Outlook. So they can read inomcing messages and select the E-Mail address of the shared mailbox as sender.

Is it possible to set the E-Mail Address of the shared mailbox as preselected sender on writing a new E-Mail or on answering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's possible if you are running Outlook (not OWA) and a third-party add-in  (or your own VBA script) that populates the From: field.